# add zero and convert as varchar to a flot using a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data where I need to add leading zeros to it. But the problem is the data type is float. So whenever I add zeros, it automatically omits them. I have tried to add leading zero to it then try to convert it to varchar(50). But the it is giving an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'wallet_sys'.

I have used following query:

```
select  (convert (varchar(50), ('0' + wallet_sys wallet_sys)))  from NewSysData1
```

What have I done wrong?

> PS: Some of the sample data are below: 17187383, 87339833, 93838793
>
> I want these to be: 017187383, 087339833, 093838793

Comment: Note that in `'0' + wallet_sys` the '0' is interpreted as the integer value 0, not as a character to put in front of the number. Change it to '1' to see that in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the zero *after* it's become a string, not before:

```
select  '0' + convert (varchar(50), (wallet_sys)) as wallet_sys  from NewSysData1
```

Normally, most people want to convert to having, say, a fixed width of result, with the appropriate number of leading zeros to make that happen. For that, it's a bit more work:

```
select RIGHT('0000000000' + convert (varchar(50), (wallet_sys wallet_sys)),10) as wallet_sys 
from NewSysData1
```

Will produce 10 digits, with as many leading zeroes as needed (The number of zeroes in the string literal should be ~equal to the number of desired digits, and this is also the 10 provided at the right hand end of the first line)

Comment: @SadatMainuddin - just spotted that `wallet_sys` was repeated. Assuming that that was an attempt to name the result column the same as the input, I've made the appropriate changes.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer. And sorry for my late reply. Please be informed that the first solution gives result but the result is like: 01.72295e+009, but it should look like: 01711234567. The second answer gives the error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'wallet_sys'.